# Get parameters from POST symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I am experiencing a major concern that I can not solve.
I developed an api with symfony 3.
I want to recover data from form in my front. With Ajax, i send data with formData().

From my controller in symfony, I get the data like this:

```
                $ file = $request->files->get('file');
                $ source = $request->request->get('source');
                $ userLastname = $request->request->get('userLastname');
                $userFirstname = $request->request->get('userFirstname');
                $text = $request->request->get('text');
```

Since my server, when symfony was in environment dev, I recovered the data (with postman).
Since then I switched to a production environment. And I can not recover the data (with postman)

I do not understand why ?

I env prod, $file, $source, $userLastname, $userFirstname and $text return all null.

Comment: what data can't you recover? what does it even mean to recover them? 
Could you please try to explain your issue a bit better? Thanks

Comment: How is the data submitted? Are you sure you are using a POST-request? What are the differences between your dev and prod environment (PHP version, OS, any changes in the code or in the dependencies)?

Comment: nothing changes... same server, same php version... Really weird

Comment: From a browser, press F12 then the use the network tab to examine exactly what data is being sent, especially the request names.

Answer (score 0):

> nothing changes... same server, same php version ...

Then it's a cache problem
Clear your ***prod*** caches by running `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`